# Small window starts to appear after boot up

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-mate, qemu

It starts to appear after boot. I did feel a bit of slowness when I use the machine.

Using Lunar, any idea how to check it, remove it, fix whatever is going on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: sorry, thanks. Lunar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On any window in Gnome you can *right-clic*k and select "Task-Manager".
That window is a GUI overview of active processes.

It will start with the window you clicked on pre-selected.
And among other things you will find the process-id of that process there.

That allows you to check via `ps axlf` or in /proc//... or any other means to find what program it actually is. From there you hopefully can find what started/opened it.